# Como pegar dados de tabelas diferentes e inserir em uma nova

Tags: php, mysqli, combobox

Boa noite, estou fazendo um trabalho para uma matéria do curso e nele tenho que trabalhar com três tabelas, no meu caso uso uma tabela cadastro cliente, uma segunda tabela cadastro carro e a terceira seria uma junção das duas cadastro aluguel a partir de dois combobox, um que pega todos os clientes cadastrados e outra todos os modelos cadastrados. Minha dúvida é: Como posso pegar esses dois dados do combobox e jogar numa terceira tabela? Existe a tabela 1 - clientes, tabela 2 - carros, tabela 3 - aluga.

Deixarei as duas partes que fiz referente a terceira página, ver_carros.php é a página e aluga.php era onde estava tentando jogar para o banco. Sei que algumas partes do aluga.php está errada porém deixei assim pois foi a ultima edição que fiz

**ver_carros.php**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Aluguel de Carros</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>



<!-- COMEÇO DA NAVBAR -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Aluguel de Carros</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="cadastro.html">Cadastrar usuário</a></li>
        <li><a href="cadastrocar.html">Cadastrar carro</a></li>
        <li><a href="ver_carros.php">Alugar carro</a></li>
        <li><a href="alugueis.php">Histórico</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- FIM DA NAVBAR -->

<h1 align="center">Aluguel de Carros</h1>

<hr>
  <form class="form-horizontal" id="alugarcarro" name="alugarcarro" method="post" action="aluga.php" onSubmit="return validaCampo(); return false;>
    <fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Nome</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <select class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome">
          <?php
            $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "clientes" ); 
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysqli_error());
        $banco = mysqli_select_db($conexao, "clientes"); 
        if (!$banco)
        die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysqli_error($conexao));
        $sql = "select id,nome from clientes order by nome;";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['nome'] . "</option>"; }
        mysqli_close($conexao);
        ?>



        </select>
        </div>
      </div>

<div class="form-group">
        <label for="select" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Carros</label>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          <select class="form-control" id="preco" name="preco">
          <?php
            $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "clientes" ); 
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
        die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysqli_error());
        $banco = mysqli_select_db($conexao, "clientes"); 
        if (!$banco)
        die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysqli_error($conexao));
        $sql = "select id,modelo,preco from carros order by preco;";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        echo "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['modelo'] . " - R$" . $row['preco'] . "</option>"; }
        mysqli_close($conexao);
        ?>

        </select>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div style="float:right;">
          <input name="alugarcarro" type="submit" id="alugarcarro" class="btn btn-success" value="Alugar carro!" />
          <input name="limpar" type="reset" id="limpar" class="btn btn-danger" value="Limpar Campos preenchidos!" />
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
  </form>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**aluga.php**

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Carro alugado com sucesso!</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php 
        $nomealuguel = $_POST ["nome"];
        $precoaluguel = $_POST ["preco"];

//Gravando no banco de dados ! conectando com o localhost - mysql
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "clientes" ); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
die ("Erro de conexão com localhost, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysqli_error());

//conectando com a tabela do banco de dados
$banco = mysqli_select_db($conexao, "clientes"); 
if (!$banco)
die ("Erro de conexão com banco de dados, o seguinte erro ocorreu -> ".mysqli_error($conexao));


//Query que realiza a inserção dos dados no banco de dados na tabela indicada acima
$query = "INSERT INTO `aluga` ( `nome` , 'preco' )
VALUES ('$nomealuguel', '$precoaluguel')";
mysqli_query($conexao,$query);
//echo "Seu cadastro foi realizado com sucesso!Agradecemos a atenção.";
//mensagem que é escrita quando os dados são inseridos normalmente.
?>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Aluguel de Carros</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="cadastro.html">Cadastrar usuário</a></li>
        <li><a href="cadastrocar.html">Cadastrar carro</a></li>
        <li><a href="ver_carros.php">Alugar carro</a></li>
        <li><a href="alugueis.php">Histórico</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="alert alert-success col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" align="center">
  <h1>Alugado com sucesso</h1>
  <?php echo $nomealuguel; ?> , você alugou um carro com sucesso!
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Desculpa se está confuso, meu primeiro post aqui.

Comment: Olá sem ter uma estrutura dos dados, apenas te posso dizer que precisas de guardar o Id (identificador único ) da pessoa e do automóvel, sugiro ainda que tenhas um booleano na terceira tabela por forma a saberes se o aluguer está activo ou não. Em termos de php não te posso ajudar muito pois não sou perito mas em termos de design de bases de dados espero te ter ajudado.

Comment: Esta dando erro? Qual erro? Este trecho esta concatenado errado: $query = "INSERT INTO `aluga` ( `nome` , 'preco' )
VALUES ('$nomealuguel', '$precoaluguel')";

Comment: Pode mostrar como são as tabelas? Você quer fazer um registo de alugueres de carros, é isso? Pode usar uma tabela de registos de alugueres que inclua a chave estrangeira de usuários e outra chave estrangeira de carros. E talvez mais datas, e tudo mais que precisar.

Comment: Eu não conheço muito de PHP, mas posso dizer que sua pergunta está confusa porque não entendi onde está a sua dificuldade. Você postou o código que fez, mas não explica o que cada página faz e, principalmente não diz se ele dá erro ou o que acontece. Procure editar para deixar a sua dificuldade bem clara, ou dificilmente alguém conseguirá te ajudar.